# Laravel Impossible to Create Root Directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-filesystem

I've checked out the other posts about this, mine seems to be unique for some reason

Essentially what I'm trying to do is store uploaded photos in the public directory for easy access, however when I store them I'm trying to store them in a user specific folder, so

```
/public/photos/$User->id/$filename.jpg
```

Right now I have Dropzone uploading the file, and I've added to my filesystem.php this statement

```
'public_uploads' => [
  'driver' => 'local',
  'root'   => public_path(),
],
```

So in theory when I access that using

```
Storage::disk('public_uploads')
```

it should retrieve the correct path

Here's my controller as well

```
$User = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
$Photo = Request::file('photo');
Storage::disk('public_uploads')->put("photos/$User->id", $Photo);
```

Then I get this error from Laravel on upload

```
{message: "Impossible to create the root directory "/censoredfilesystem/public/Photos/1".",…}
```

No idea where the period is coming from and any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks all!

- Zach

Comment: Do you have permissions?

Comment: check all permissions if your're using Linux

Comment: Permissions for what? I've set permissions correctly for App and Storage, do I need to set others?

Comment: You need to put braces around `$User->id` in `Storage::disk('public_uploads')->put("photos/{$User->id}", $Photo);`, as far as I know only variables work inside double quotes, but not object property calls. And you should also check that the process that runs php (apache or ngnix) has the permissions to write in the public folder.

Comment: Tried that, also added permissions for the public folder and neither worked, I think it's an error with the folder naming format rather than the permissions

Comment: Maybe `photos != Photos`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Fixed it unknowningly by setting permissions according to comments, I used

```
chown -R www-data:root .
```

in the root of my directory

Edit: I used `www-data:root`, meaning set the owner of everything inside the Laravel directory to `www-data` (the webserver) and `root` being `root` obviously. If you do this you should do it with a non-root user or just to `www-data`

Comment: But that will give www-data access to the whole laravel structure, you should only give www-data to /censoredfilesystem/public/Photos/. So sudo chown :www-data /censoredfilesystem/public/Photos/ and sudo chmod 775 /censoredfilesystem/public/Photos/

Comment: how much is the risk of running this command?

Answer (score 2):

**First, remove these folders**

```
/public/storage

/storage/app/public
```

**Then run the following command**

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to go into /storage/app/public/ and create the folder in which you want to store the files if not existing i.e /storage/app/public/*addfolder* (and give yourseld permission to fopen and fwrite etc if admin or working on a server)